# Carriage Return issue with SerialPort

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'm trying to communicate with a laboratory instrument that accepts a few different commands. The instrument uses just a carriage return to terminate -- no line feed.

When I use RealTerm and set the connection as required, I can send one of the ASCII commands along with a `CR` character. The instrument provides the correct response.

When using .NET's `SerialPort` object however, it seems like `\r` in C# isn't necessarily correct, because whenever I send it, my instrument gives an error code relating to a printer timeout/error (the RS-232 port is considered a "printer" but the manual specifies how to connect to a PC as well).

I have certainly verified that my port's `NewLine` property is set to `\r`. Here's a couple things I've tried:

```
_port.WriteLine(command); // error at the instrument once this executes.
_port.Write(command + _port.NewLine); // also error.
_port.Write(command); // executes without error, but next line errors:
_port.Write(_port.NewLine);
```

Is there some fundamental difference between the `CR` in RealTerm vs. `\r` in C#? Or could there be something else coming into play here?

Comment: Did you try to configure _port.NewLine, i.e. _port.NewLine="\r" ?

Comment: Run a tool like [portmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) comparing a good manual command with  what your code is sending, the difference is the issue.

Comment: A program like RealTerm will translate an Enter key press to any desired character(s).  As configured for the connection.  Like the ones you haven't tried yet and are common, like "\n" and "\r\n"

Comment: @HansPassant I had, in RealTerm, tried the different combinations, the instrument doesn't care much about line feeds. I had not tried doing the same in my code, as I figured that would be the same, but I will try that.

Comment: @AlexK. I had tried portmon and a few similar utilities but was unable to get any of them to work. Just some cryptic error messages.

Comment: Parity bit configuration problem (possible error source if your commands are very short) ? May you indicate the content of the first command that works and the next line that fails ?

Comment: @Graffito The command is "DAT". The instrument configuration is for no parity bit, and that is how my `SerialPort` is configured as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this figured out, for my use case anyways -- I needed to set `DtrEnable = true;` to stop the errors. I did get a program (called "AccessPort") to successfully run and spy on my port. While both my code and RealTerm were writing the same exact bytes, I noticed that the bitmasks in the driver configuration were a bit different. Even though I had all handshaking and and flow control disabled in RealTerm it was still enabling DTR, confirmed after browsing the driver's header files. Doing the same in my code fixed the issue.